# Create Lite version of my app with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I created my iPhone app with MonoTouch and deployed it to the AppStore. Now I want to add a free lite version of the same app. What is the best way to do this with MonoTouch/MonoDevelop?

So far I created a new Provisioning Profile for the lite version. I can change the build options to use the full or the lite profile. But what else do I have to change and how? I think at least the app name should be changed, but how???

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

The way I do these things is to create a new project, then add the existing c# files from the first project as a link.  You will see this option on the "add existing file" dialog.  Keep in mind all your Icon/Splash screen files will have to be copied though, MonoDevelop doesn't handle these right if they are linked.

Just a side note, you can get by with less provisioning profiles. Create one as com.yourcompany.*, then name your apps com.yourcompany.yourapp1, yourapp2, etc.

So I have a profile for Development, AdHoc, and AppStore, but I have several apps deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than link files, I prefer to make three projects: A library project which will have all the UILogic called X.Touch.Core and two more which will have a reference of the Core. X.Touch.Lite and X.Touch.Premium. This way you don't need to have linked files, it can be painful. You can put a file called settings.xml and perform some feature toggling there.